# C#, Windows Services: ServiceBase.Run with several services of the same type

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to run several similar services via `ServiceBase.Run(ServiceBase[] )` but it's only running the first one.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6esb073b(VS.80).aspx) doesn't explicitly deny this; does this excerpt mean that they all must be different types?  (the bold is by me, not MSDN)

> Call this overload in the main() function of the service executable to load an array of **associated services**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the intent.  The idea here is that you can have a single executable create "multiple services" instead of just a single type of service.

When a service is registered with the SCM, it's expected that each service is unique.  This would suggest (and I believe it's the case) that each element in your array must be a unique implementation of [ServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx).

If you really are just trying to have multiple copies of the **same** service, I would rethink your design.  Just have the service fire off multiple threads using the same method, and it will provide that same effect with a single service instance.

Comment: The multiple threads was the original design and I was just experimenting with this.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: It should be possible to have 2 Services implementing the same type. You just have to make sure that each service has a unique service name.

This scenario is particularly useful if you want to have 2 services having the same functionality but using different configurations. Say different shared folders to read files from or different databases to connect to.

I have created a windows service library called Daemoniq. It supports running multiple windows services in one process. http://code.google.com/p/daemoniq/wiki/MultipleWindowsServicesOneProcess.

Comment: While it's possible, as soon as you name them separately, they're in essence two separate services ;)  That being said, your approach is fine.